# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined, how to?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const { channel } = message.member.voice;

    const permissions = channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has("CONNECT"))
        return message.reply("Je n'est pas les permissions de rejoindre votre channel.");
    if (!permissions.has("SPEAK"))
        return message.reply("Je ne peux pas parler dans ce channel vocal.");

    const search = args.join(" ");
    const videoPattern = /^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$/gi;
    const playlistPattern = /^.*(list=)([^#\&\?]*).*/gi;
    const url = args[0];
    const urlValid = videoPattern.test(args[0]);

    const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
                          ^^^^^ÊRROR HERE^^^^^^
    const queueConstruct = {
        textChannel: message.channel,
        channel,
        connection: null,
        songs: [],
        loop: false,
        volume: 50,
        playing: true
    };

    let songInfo = null;
    let song = null;

    if (urlValid) {
        try {
            songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(url);
            song = {
                title: songInfo.title,
                url: songInfo.video_url,
                duration: songInfo.length_seconds,
            };
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.message.includes("copyright")) {
                return message
                    .reply("⛔ Cette vidéo est copyright, elle ne peut donc être jouée. ⛔")
                    .catch(console.error);
            } else {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    } else {
        try {
            const results = await youtube.searchVideos(search, 1);
            songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(results[0].url);
            song = {
                title: songInfo.title,
                url: songInfo.video_url,
                duration: songInfo.length_seconds,
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    if (serverQueue) {
        serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        return serverQueue.textChannel
            .send(`✅ **${song.title}** a été ajoutée a la queue par ${message.author}`)
            .catch(console.error);
    } else {
        queueConstruct.songs.push(song);
    }

    if (!serverQueue) message.client.queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct);
```

When the code launches normally it should play some music, but when I run the code it doesn't go as expected, it tells me that the get is not defined ...
Could you help me please ?

I do not understand why it does that knowing that before it works ... If you help me it will be very useful!
there is not all the code, because otherwise the site will ask me for more details sorry ...

Comment: That error is telling you there's no property `queue` on `message.client`. Cannot read property 'get' of  `message.client.queue`, because `message.client.queue` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

this error comes up whenever you want to access to a non existent property in an object. Are you sure about existence of this `queue` property in `message.client`? According to [discord.js doc](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client), there isn't any property called `queue` in client object which is accessible via message object. For assurance log the `message.client` to find available properties via that object.

Comment: I'll watch, I'll tell you more as soon as I have something new!